What Lipschitz functions can be represented as an accumalating integral?
In class I saw that for a Riemann integrable function $f:[a, b] \to \Bbb R$, the function $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)dt $ is continuous and is even Lipschitz (There is a constant $M>0$ such that for all $x, y \in [a, b] $, $|F(x)-F(y)|\le M\cdot |x-y|$). this led me to thinking; what Lipschitz functions can be represented as an integral of another function?
I think such a function must be differentiable (at least in some point), but I couldn't prove that, nor could find a counterexample. would really appreciate a hint/ direction.

If one uses the lebesgue integral, this holds if and only if the function is absolutely continuous, see here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity under "equivalent definitions". I assume you are talking about riemann integrals, in which case the integrand needs to be bounded; in this case f is Lipschitz, as you claim.

@geetha290krm it is True (at least in Riemann integrals), beacuse of the triangle inequality. |f| is an integrable function and therefore bounded, say by $M$. then $|F(x+h)-F(x)| = |\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt| \le \int_{x}^{x+h}|f(t)|dt \le |h|\cdot M$.

@geetha290krm $f$ is Riemann-integrable in a bounded interval, so it is a bounded function.

Side remark: if $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Lipschitz continuous, then Rademacher’s theorem tells us that $F$ is differentiable at almost every point of $[a,b]$, relative to Lebesgue measure. In simpler terms, this means apart from a ‘small’ set of exceptional points, the function $F$ is differentiable everywhere else. So, Lipschitzness already encodes a lot of differentiability properties.
I am not surprised you weren’t able to prove $F$ is differentiable (at even some point); the above theorem by Rademacher is pretty non-trivial. In fact, I think proving differentiability at some point (although it sounds easier) isn’t actually easier than proving Rademacher’s theorem itself.

Next, in real analysis, there is a very strong generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus, to Lebesgue integrals, and this is related to a notion known as absolute continuity. You do not need to know the specific details. All you need to know is that

if $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, then it is absolutely continuous (AC for short).
if $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is AC, then there is a Lebesgue-integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in [a,b]$, we have $F(x)=F(a)+\int_{[a,x]}f\,dm$, and furthermore, for a.e $x\in [a,b]$ (i.e for ‘most points’), we have that $F’(x)$ exists and equals $f(x)$. Again, you do not need to know what exactly a Lebesgue integral is; you can just take it to mean ‘an important and worthy generalization of the Riemann integral’.

By combining these two statements, it follows that if $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Lipschitz, then there exists a Lebesgue-integrable function $f:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ such that for all $x\in [a,b]$, we have $F(x)=F(a)+\int_{[a,x]}f\,dm$, and furthermore, for a.e $x\in [a,b]$, we have $F’(x)$ exists and equals $f(x)$. Now, it is a very elementary fact that if $F$ is Lipschitz with constant $M$, and if $F’(x)$ exists, then $|F’(x)|\leq M$; thus for a.e $x\in [a,b]$ we have $|f(x)|\leq M$. So, with these remarks, we have the following theorem:

Theorem.
If $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ is Lipschitz with constant $M$, then there is a function $f\in L^{\infty}([a,b])$ with $\|f\|_{\infty}\leq M$ such that for all $x\in [a,b]$, $F(x)=F(a)+\int_{[a,x]}f\,dm$.
Conversely, if $f\in L^{\infty}([a,b])$, then for any $c\in\Bbb{R}$, the function $F:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}$ defined as $F(x):=c+\int_{[a,x]}f\,dm$ is Lipschitz with constant at most $\|f\|_{\infty}$.

(The converse is easy to prove). In short, this says a function is Lipschitz if and only if it can be expressed as a Lebesgue-integral of an essentially-bounded function.
However, we cannot do better than this; we can’t guarantee that $f$ is Riemann-integrable. Indeed, let $K\subset [0,1]$ be a fat Cantor set, and let $F:[0,1]\to\Bbb{R}$ be defined as $F(x):=\int_{[0,x]}\chi_K\,dm$, where $\chi_K$ is the indicator function. By the (easy) second part of the theorem above, the function is Lipschitz. If however we could express $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)\,dt$ for some Riemann-integrable $f$, then we would have (by the second bullet point above (keeping in mind Lebesgue integrals are a generalization of Riemann’s)) that $f=\chi_K$ a.e. However, this is impossible because $f$ being Riemann-integrable implies, by Lebesgue’s theorem for Riemann-integrability, that the set of discontinuities of $f$ has measure-zero. However, $\chi_K$ is discontinuous at every point of $K$, which is a set of positive Lebesgue measure, so it is impossible for $f$ to equal $\chi_K$ a.e.
So, long story short, if you want a true correspondence between Lipschitz functions and integrals of (essentially) bounded functions, you need to use the Lebesgue integral; Riemann’s integral doesn’t suffice, because as shown above, there exist Lipschitz functions $F$ which cannot be expressed as Riemann integrals of a Riemann-integrable $f$.
